# avoid url on popup window title

Tags: javascript

I've a pop up window which i'm opening using below script. I want to avoid the url of the pop up window which appears on pop window title.

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'WIDTH=300,HEIGHT=250');
```

is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2):

Give the document a title using the `<title>` element. This is good and meaningful and the best way.

If the document does not have a title and is on the same domain, though, you can access its `document`:

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'WIDTH=300,HEIGHT=250');
newWindow.document.title = 'Hello, world!';
```

Comment: Although i set window title as'MyTitle', i get this in title "https://localhost:9444/- MyTitle - Window Internet Explorer". I don't want "https://localhost:9444/" & "Window Internet Explorer" in my title

Comment: @Pankaj: I don't really remember the specifics of Internet Explorer, but the "Windows Internet Explorer" part is definitely impossible to remove from your webpage, and the URL probably is too. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There's more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

If you're looking to hide the location bar, add "location=0" to your 3rd argument. If you want to affect the window title, make sure to include a  in the page that's loading in the popup.